# Can I make a serializer fail silently?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have to serializer a list of email addresses. If one of them contains a wrong character (in one case, it was a ":" at the end of the address) my serializer throws an error, rejects serializing the whole set of addresses and returns a HTTP 400. Is there a way to "pop" the faulty email address from the list but still serialize the remaining correct addresses?

### View:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def match(self, request):
    serializer = FriendFinderSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        contacts = serializer.validated_data
        matched, unmatched = self.match_contacts(contacts)
        serialized_matched = FriendFinderSerializer(matched, many=True)
        serialized_unmatched = FriendFinderSerializer(unmatched, many=True)
        data = {
            'matched': serialized_matched.data,
            'unmatched': serialized_unmatched.data,
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### Serializer:

```
class FriendFinderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    record_id = serializers.CharField()
    phone_numbers = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), required=False)
    email_addresses = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.EmailField(), required=False)
    relationship_id = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    relationship_status = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A place to start would be to iterate over `request.data` and handle each element within a loop. This is definitely a break from the norm and you'll need to determine how to handle cases where there is good and bad data.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def match(self, request):
    successful_data = []
    error_data = []
    for element in request.data:
        serializer = FriendFinderSerializer(data=element, many=False)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            contacts = serializer.validated_data
            matched, unmatched = self.match_contacts(contacts)
            serialized_matched = FriendFinderSerializer(matched, many=True)
            serialized_unmatched = FriendFinderSerializer(unmatched, many=True)
            successful_data.append({
                'matched': serialized_matched.data,
                'unmatched': serialized_unmatched.data,
            })
        else:
            error_data.append(serializer.errors)
    # Determine what status to return and how to handle successes and errors.
```

Personally, I'd either make smaller requests rather than posting all the data or handle the case in which an error in one `FriendFinderSerializer` causes all to fail. What you're attempting to do is likely to cause you more pain than the other options.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. I ended up sorting erronous and clean data in a for loop like you suggested and doing the matching after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**This is kind of a hack, but it works.**

You need to define a custom field and there you need to override `to_internal_value` method of the field. Like this:

```
class CustomField(serializers.Field):

    def __init__(self, custom_validation, *args, **kwargs):
        self.custom_validation=custom_validation  # <-- Here pass your custom validation regex
        super(CustomField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
            return obj

    def to_internal_value(self, obj):
        try:
            match = re.search(self.custom_validation, obj)  # <-- validate the value against regex
            if match:
                return obj
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        return None  # <-- If exception occurs, return None
```

Or override the `EmailField` like this:

```
class CustomEmailField(serializer.EmailField):
     def run_validation(self,*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(CustomEmailField, self).run_validation(*args,**kwargs)  # <-- Runs validation, but it fails, returns None
        except:
            return None
```

And use it in the Serializer like this:

```
email = CustomField(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")  # regex for email
```

Or

```
email = CustomEmailField()
```

And if you want to pop the invalid values from `ListField`, then you can override `to_representation` like this:

```
class CustomListField(serializers.ListField):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        childs = super(CustomListField, self).to_representation(data)
        new_childs = []
        for child in childs:
            if child:
                new_childs.append(child)
        return new_childs
```

Then, use it in the Serializer:

```
email_addresses = CustomListField(child=CustomEmailField(), required=False)
```